# How to free memory of previous stack frame in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-management, garbage-collection, v8

I have a number of functions calling the next one in a chain, processing a rather large set of data to an equally large set of different data:

```
function first_step(input_data, second_step_callback)
{
  result = ... // do some processing
  second_step_callback(result, third_step);
}

function second_step(intermediate_data, third_step_callback)
{
  result = ... // do some processing
  third_step_callback(result);
}

function third_step(intermediate_data) { }

first_step(huge_data, second_step);
```

In `third_step` I am running out of memory (Chrome seems to kill the tab when memory usage reaches about 1.5 GB).

I think, when reaching `third_step()`, the `input_data` from `first_step()` is still retained, because `first_step()` is on the call stack, isn't it? At least when the debugger is running, I can see the data.

Obviously I don't need it anymore. In `first_step()` there is no code after `second_step_callback(result, third_step);`. Maybe if I could free that memory, my tab might survive processing a data set of this size. Can I do this?

Comment: 1.5 gigabytes is a lot more than *"rather large"* in clientside code, you're sure you don't have an infinite loop somewhere

Comment: It occurs when processing an 300 MB input file (https://github.com/AndreKR/XdebugFlamechartConverter) and seems reasonable memory usage. I can't really break it up into chunks because at some point I have to hold the whole tree in memory. That's why I want to throw away the raw data before I continue processing the tree into the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a lot more of what you're really doing that is using memory, it's hard for us to tell whether you're just using too much memory or whether you just need to let earlier memory get freed up.

And, memory in Javascript is not "owned" by stack frames so the premise of the question seems to make a bit of a wrong assumption.  Memory in Javascript is garbage collected and is eligible for GC when no live, reachable code still has a reference to the data and will get garbage collected the next time the garbage collector gets to run (during JS idle time).

That said, if you have code that makes a succession of nested function calls like your question shows, you can reduce the amount of memory usage, by doing some of these things:

1. Clear variables that hold large data (just set them to `null`) that are no longer needed.
2. Reduce the use of intermediate variables that hold large data.
3. Reduce the copying of data.
4. Reduce string manipulations with intermediate results because each one creates block of memory that then has to be reclaimed.
5. Clear the stack by using `setTimeout()` to run the next step in the chain and allow the garbage collector a chance to do its thing on earlier temporary variables.
6. Restructure how you process or store the data to fundamentally use less memory.

Comment: It seems to my question (how to clear memory retained by the call stack) only number 5 is an answer (it's only possible with `setTimeout()`). Number 1 seems interesting, but if I would do `input_data = undefined` in `first_step()` would the memory for the function arguments actually be freed?

Comment: @AndreKR - These are all techniques to reduce the amount of concurrent memory being used.  I figured they are all relevant to your overall problem.  1) and 5) are ways to improve the usage of your sequence of function calls.

Comment: @AndreKR - Setting something to `null` when the object or string or array is being used elsewhere (like in a function argument) won't help you much since the item still won't be eligible for garbage collection.  To help you with this technique, you need to `null` out things that are no longer being used and nobody else has a reference to the data and make sure the garbage collector has a chance to run.

Comment: @AndreKR - And, no memory is technically retained by the call stack or stack frame which makes your question a little bit hard to address directly.  That's not how garbage collection works - that's more how a language like C++ works.  To make something eligible for garbage collection, you just need to make sure no live code has access to the data any more and that you give the garbage collector a chance to run.

Comment: Does that mean that when the debugger is closed, no code has access to it and it is therefore eligible for collection?

Comment: @AndreKR - How the debugger uses memory would be entirely implementation specific in a given browser.  It's memory is not a normal Javascript variable.  It may or may not use garbage collection at all and may or may not use the same memory sub-system as the Javascript engine.  That question would have to be answered by either devising a number of tests to test a specific browser or studying source code of a specific open-source browser.